# Nested SemaphoreSlims, Safety, and Deadlock

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a class using `SemaphoreSlim`, which calls another class using `SemaphoreSlim`. It is running without deadlock or race condition.

What is the general guideline on this?

```
try
{
    await _semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
    DoWork();
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}
finally
{
    _semaphoreSlim.Release();   
}

private void DoWork(){
try
{
    await _semaphoreSlim2.WaitAsync();
    //more work
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}
finally
{
    _semaphoreSlim2.Release();  
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you're using a `SemaphoreSlim` as a kind of "mutex" ("mutual exclusion") primitive.

Each mutex should be used to protect a specific set of data. So it's appropriate to use different mutexes for different sets of data. As a general guideline, fine-grained mutexes are better than coarse-grained mutexes.

When you're dealing with multiple mutexes, you want to always ensure that they are acquired in the same order. Your example has code that holds `_semaphoreSlim` then calling code that acquires `_semaphoreSlim2`. This is fine, but you should document it, because you don't ever want code that holds `_semaphoreSlim2` to call code that acquires `_semaphoreSlim`. That could cause a deadlock.

Comment: "As a general guideline, fine-grained mutexes are better than coarse-grained mutexes." What do you mean by FG mutexes and CG mutexes?

Comment: Each mutex should be responsible for protecting the minimum amount of data. So "fine-grained" means there are more mutexes, each one responsible for a smaller amount of data; "course-grained" would mean there are fewer mutexes responsible for larger amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to ensure the locks are always acquired in the same order, so if someone else can call DoWork, and something inside DoWork could end up calling your top block of code, then you have a reverse order and potential for deadlock.

Comment: Thats true, I am aware of that. SO is limited, I should be able to give more answer.